# Inserting a control into another control at specific location?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with win forms. I have two forms : my main form, `Form1` and a Form I made called `TextBlock`. I am making a text editor, where you can place text boxes around a page, and edit them (think word).

Here are my two forms.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text File|*.txt";
        var result = saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new 
            StreamWriter(saveFileDialog.OpenFile());
            writer.Write(tb_Main.Text);
            writer.Dispose();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }

    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button_tb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBlock tb_edit = new TextBlock();
        tb_edit.Text = "New Text Block";
        // tb_edit.Multiline = true;
        // tb_edit.Size = new Size(100,100);
        // tb_edit.MinimumSize = new Size(50, 50);
        tb_edit.form1 = this;

        tb_edit.TopLevel = false;
        tb_edit.btn_accepttb.BringToFront();
        tb_Main.Controls.Add(tb_edit);
        tb_edit.Show();
        tb_edit.BringToFront();

    }
}
```

and my custom form here:

```
 public partial class TextBlock : Form
    {
        public Form1 form1;
        public TextBlock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_accepttb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb_edit = new TextBox();
            tb_edit.Text = "New Text Block";
            tb_edit.Multiline = true;
            tb_edit.Size = this.Size;
            int dif = form1.tb_Main.Lines.Count()*(int)tb_edit.Font.Size;
            Point loca = new Point(this.Location.X,this.Location.Y+dif);
            tb_edit.Location = this.Location;


            form1.tb_Main.Controls.Add(tb_edit);
            tb_edit.Show();
            tb_edit.BringToFront();
            form1.tb_Main.Controls.Remove(this);
        }
    }
```

What it does: it makes a copy my TextBlock, for placement and resizing purposes. when you have it where you want and how big you want, you click the button, and it replaces itself with a regular textbox, of that size, in that position.

What I want it to do: currently it is working with one exception. I am adding it to the controls, of tb_Main (my main textbox, it takes up the whole form) in Form1, it shows up. its the right size, except when i fill tb_Main with text, and i scroll, the new textbox stays where it is while its parent scrolls behind it.

Question : if I scroll down into my document and decide I want this textbox here, how do I ensure its position relative to the scroll of the textbox im putting it in. so when I scroll on, it basically stays embedded in the page where I put it (when I say "page" im referring to my tb_Main).

Comment: You need to subclass the `textbox(tb_Main)` get the `WM_VSCROLL` message and manually scroll the child textbox eg change the location according to the scroll value.

Comment: ill be testiing this in about an hour. please repost as as answer so i can upvote if it works cuz that sounds like exactly what im trying to do! thanks i will come back and accept if it works, specifically that wm_scroll value is what i needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to create a `richtextbox` instead of `textbox`. It has all capabilities of `textbox` and way more. This example works **only** with a `richtextbox`.

Subclassed `richtextbox`:

```
class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox  {

    [DllImport( "user32.dll" )]
    private static extern bool GetScrollInfo( IntPtr hwnd, SBOrientation fnBar,
        ref SCROLLINFO lpsi );

    [StructLayout( LayoutKind.Sequential )]
    private struct SCROLLINFO {
        public uint cbSize;
        public ScrollInfoMask fMask;
        public int nMin;
        public int nMax;
        public uint nPage;
        public int nPos;
        public int nTrackPos;
    }

    private enum ScrollInfoMask : uint {
        SIF_RANGE = 0x1,
        SIF_PAGE = 0x2,
        SIF_POS = 0x4,
        SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL = 0x8,
        SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,
        SIF_ALL = ( SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS ),
    }

    private enum SBOrientation : int {
        SB_HORZ = 0x0,
        SB_VERT = 0x1,
    }

    private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x115;
    private const int SB_LINEUP = 0;
    private const int SB_LINEDOWN = 1;
    private const int SB_PAGEUP = 2;
    private const int SB_PAGEDOWN = 3;
    private const int SB_THUMBPOSITION = 4;
    private const int SB_THUMBTRACK = 5;
    private const int SB_TOP = 6;
    private const int SB_BOTTOM = 7;
    private const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 8;

    private bool isThumbTrack = false;
    private TextBox childTextbox = null;
    private int scrollPos = 0;


    public MyTextBox( TextBox textbox ) { //here you pass the child textbox you want to scroll

        childTextbox = textbox;

    }

    protected override void OnVScroll( EventArgs e ) {
        if( childTextbox == null ) { base.OnVScroll( e ); return; }

        SCROLLINFO si = new SCROLLINFO();
        si.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf( si );
        si.fMask = ScrollInfoMask.SIF_ALL;

        GetScrollInfo( this.Handle, SBOrientation.SB_VERT, ref si );

        //there is a difference when the user uses the thumb to get scroll pos.
        //When user uses the thumb we get *nTrackPos* otherwise *nPos*
        if( isThumbTrack == true ) {
            childTextbox.Location = new Point( childTextbox.Location.X, childTextbox.Location.Y - 
                                               (si.nTrackPos - scrollPos ) );

            isThumbTrack = false;
            scrollPos = si.nTrackPos;
        }
        else {
            childTextbox.Location = new Point( childTextbox.Location.X, childTextbox.Location.Y -
                                               ( si.nPos - scrollPos ) );

            scrollPos = si.nPos;
        }


        base.OnVScroll( e );
    }

    protected override void WndProc( ref Message m ) {
        int wParam;

        if(m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL ) {

            wParam = m.WParam.ToInt32();
            wParam &= 0xFFFF; //get low 16 bits of wParam

            //Check if user is using the thumb to scroll
            if( wParam == SB_THUMBTRACK ) {
                isThumbTrack = true;
            }

        }

        base.WndProc( ref m );
    }

}
```

Comment: it  occurred to me last night that `RichTextBox` would work better  so i have already changed to  `RichTextBox` anyway and this works perfect.Thank You! if you dont mind though, can you explain a little of this to me? as i understand, were extending RichTextBox. i am self taught and i understand most of this new class... can you explain : private enum ScrollInfoMask : uint {
        SIF_RANGE = 0x1,
        SIF_PAGE = 0x2,
        SIF_POS = 0x4,
        SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL = 0x8,
        SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,
        SIF_ALL = ( SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS ),
    }

Comment: sorry bad form i know, specifically, i dont use uint to much, and i dont understand the value 0x8 etc

Comment: @Vanethrane `GetScrollInfo` is an *unmanaged* function so you have to use the exact signature. This one uses `uint` which is *unsigned int* for the `ScrollInfoMask` enum. Don't ask about it just use it as is.

Comment: @Vanethrane We want to get the position of the scroll bar. There are 2 positions, one when we use directly the thumb `nTrackPos` and one wen we are not `nPos`. In order to do it we call `GetScrollInfo` and we pass the arguments.

Comment: I appreciate your candor. and the effective answer. im just too curious for my own good! lol. i dont intend to change the code as its working. but im the kind of guy who needs to know how... so thank you for your eloquent answer... im off to do some reading on unsigned integers! thanks again

Comment: @Vanethrane The important one is the struct `SCROLLINFO`. We pass a pointer to it thus the `ref` keyword. The `fMask`  in this struct says the system which member of the struct you want to get. We say `SIF_ALL` meaning we want all members when in reality we want only two: `nTrackPos`, `nPos` but that is not a problem, more is better :)

Comment: bella! thank you for the explanation. very thorough. id up vote again if i could. lol.

Comment: @Vanethrane [GetScrollInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollinfo)